# $this->db->update(); function in Codigniter is not working

Tags: php, codeigniter, codeigniter-3

I used the `$this->db->update();` function to update a field in a table using Codeigniter. I have the following model function to do this :

```
function addBills($fdata) {    
    if (!empty($fdata)) {    
        if ($this->db->affected_rows()) {
            if ($this->db->update('store_update_stock', array('bill_status'=>'Added'),
                array('update_stock_id' => $fdata['bill_id']))) {
                return true;
            }               
        }
    }
    return FALSE;
}
```

As an example, $fdata contains a bill_id, for example: 805 which matches with the update_stock_id in my table. Those values are outputting correctly, if used manually.

In the controller, I have:

```
if (!empty($files)) {
    foreach ($files as $fname) {
        $fdata[] = array(
                     'bill_id' => $this->input->post('bill'),
                     'file_name' => $fname,                    
                     'status' => 1
                    );
    }    
    $this->Item_model->addBills($fdata);
}
```

### Expected Result

I want to update the bill_status as "Added" when matching the update_stock_id in the table.

### Output

There is no update of the table

**Why is the table not updating, when using variable data?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you are calling `$this->db->affected_rows()` before you do the update and therefore returning always `false`. You need to change the order of functions like this:

```
function addBills($fdata) {    
    if (!empty($fdata)) {           
       $this->db->update('store_update_stock', array('bill_status'=>'Added'), array('update_stock_id' => $fdata['bill_id']));
       if ($this->db->affected_rows()) {
            return true;
        } 
        else { 
            return FALSE;             
        }
    }
}
```

see: [affected_rows()](https://codeigniter.com/userguide3/database/db_driver_reference.html?highlight=affected_rows#CI_DB_driver::affected_rows) and [Updating Data](https://codeigniter.com/userguide3/database/query_builder.html#updating-data)

---

> If I change the code as you suggest, I get no output. If I use `array('update_stock_id' => 805')` hard
> coded, the update is working fine.

This is because your array is returned indexed. Your controller function has a foreach loop, within it has an array, which gets indexed:

```
foreach ($files as $fname) {
  $fdata[] = array(...);
}
```

Since you are expecting just one bill_id, you use the first (zero indexed array element):

```
array('update_stock_id' => $fdata[0]['bill_id']))
```

Comment: If I changed the code as your suggestion, got the same result as per my question. If I used, array('update_stock_id' => 805') as hard coding, the update is working fine.

Comment: check with `print_r($fdata['bill_id'])` what's inside the array, most likely you need something like `array('update_stock_id' => $fdata[0]['bill_id']))`